# Is it possible to create database manager like phpMyAdmin using Entity Framework?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, visual-studio-2013

The goal of this app would be a support for any database that is supported by EF. Well actually I need it only to be able to create tables, modify records in the tables, and modify columns of the tables. As for now (I am a newbie) I can't imagine how to modify an existing table by adding or removing it's columns without pressing "Update model from database" in the VS environment - 
that is, programmatically. If it is impossible, making it with SQL queries would be OK for me...

Comment: Just to let you know, it's likely that this question will be closed for being too broad. In general, yes, it's theoretically possible, but *how*... that's a **very** large question, there's a great many ways one might approach that problem, and all of them are way too much to explain in a StackOverflow answer. If you're thinking of trying it, do some research, have a go, and ask more specific things as and when you run into problems. The Stack Overflow community is generally opposed to just telling you how to write entire apps; that's basically asking for someone else to do your work for you.

Answer (score 1):

Entity Framework is designed to generate DML (Data Modelling Language) statements i.e. `SELECT`, `UPDATE`, `INSERT` and `DELETE` statements against a database. It is not designed to generate DDL (Data Definition Language) statements, i.e. `CREATE`, `ALTER`, `DROP` etc, which are used to modify the database schema. Therefore Entity Framework is not the correct tool for the requirement you describe.

Comment: Agree,. Few words more: EF represent a level of abstraction over database, phpMyAdmin is direct sql (mysgl) application, showing all nuances

Answer (score 0):

I am quite sure you can. While I have never tried it with Entity Framework (you should use ADO.NET nowadays), it should be possible. The tasks you consider (creating tables, modifying tables, or modifying records) is eventually done by sending the corresponding SQL `CREATE TABLE` or `ALTER TABLE` or `UPDATE` commands to the RDBMS.
*As an aside, just bear in mind that relational databases usually do not allow for easy adding/removing of database columns. The so called no-SQL databases do, however.*

Comment: EF has no tools for manipulating database schema. It is not designed to generate DML statements.